# Lithium Ion Battery Charge & Discharge via Shared Input & Output Lead

Tags: batteries, charge, lithium

I'm seeking to rebuild a few ancient NiCad & NiMh batteries for some vintage laptops I'm fond of, and in the process would like to convert them to Li-Ion. I'll be placing the lithium cells behind off the shelf BMS boards and the original output voltages from the packs are suitable to multiples of 3.7vdc:

1. 13.2v (full charge) for one, so using 6x 18650s at 3S
2. 7.2 (full charge) for the other, and planning to use 8x 14500s at 2S

Where I'm running into trouble though is charging. To charge the lithium cells safely and completely, I'm planning to use small Li-Ion/LiPo charge boards with built-in voltage boost (i.e., to get from the wall wart's 7.5v to 8.4v) and protection circuitry. I don't want to modify the laptops themselves or their chargers, and want all the Li-Ion conversion gear to exist *inside* the new battery packs. That presents a challenge because the laptops charge *and* discharge from the same 2 conductors.

I'll need a circuit to steer current through the charger or bypass it depending on whether the laptop is running on AC (charging) or battery (discharging). Every charging circuit I've researched features a separate input / source vs. output / load. I drew up the below circuit using P-channel FETs in 3rd quadrant operation, but immediately realized the BMS is feeding into the charger.

Best I've been able to come up with is is placing a current-sensing IC (e.g., LT1494) at the positive input/output and using its output to trigger the gates of two FETs, one enhancement and one depletion. I.e., if current is flowing into the battery, the charger's FET is turned on and the BMS' FET is turned off, and visa versa.

Seems like there must be a better way?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: B1,B2,B3 must all go to cell V+ or all V- (not as shown) and CC,CV and 10% CC CUTOFF charge specs shown with battery current only sensor. Reduce CV for safety.

Comment: Yes, the BMS to18650 connection part is indeed drawn badly. It's connected correctly in application. The reversing / current steering question remains however...

Comment: No need to steer, just regulate battery current and voltage only with hysteresis And pull both FETs.. I.e.once cutoff is achieved regulate to 3.7V to 3.8V Min per cell if drops below then restart CC,CV cutoff cycle with time limit.

Comment: Leaving charger on at 4.2V for extended periods heats up battery and wears out faster.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 's comment re 4.2V needs even further emphasis. A LiIon cell using CCCV charging is charged to 4.2V (typically) and then held at 4.2V until current drops to some fraction of Imax - say C/4. || If instead you leave 4.2V applied semi-indefinitely cells will SOON be damaged, before not too long will be destroyed, and you run the risk of plating out metallic Lithium and having a vent-with-flame event. | If utter capacity is not the aim then a CC only method extends cycle ife usefully. Charge at ay C/1 (if the manufacturer allows) and terminate when 4.2V is reached.

Comment: I agree drop the CV mode will extend life @ 25%CC cutoff is better than 10%CC while some squeeze juice in till 5%CC at the expense of charge cycle endurance or lifetime Ah.

Comment: I'm missing something. This all makes sense, but just seems to reinforce the idea that I need the charger and therefore a steering circuit. Charging via the basic BMS alone is graceless (i.e., not current adjustable, charges to and holds at cutoff). The little charger board uses a CCCV algorithm and allows me to adjust current (targeting 1C), then shuts down once charging is completed unless voltage drops to an adjustable level indicating the cells are discharged.

Comment: The battery charger needs to manage battery I,V only, surplus power runs the device too while it draws from both yet only provided by charger.

Comment: Thank you for the continued insight! The charge and discharge leads are one and the same though. Voltage from the laptop's supply is unregulated and until pulled down by a connected battery, measures 20v. If that is just connected to the battery, bad things will happen (even if it's through the BMS, as holding cells at 4.2v is "bad" as you've mentioned). I need current to follow through the charger and not direct to the battery when charging, and visa versa when discharging as the charger board won't supply battery power via it's input.